В чем разница между static/dynamic dispatch и ранним/поздним связыванием?
Хотелось бы узнать, в чём принципиальное различие между данными процессами.

О чём речь? При чём здесь C#?

Принципиального различия не вижу, речь об одном и том-же, просто разные авторы описывают одно и то-же с разной семантикой - как вызывается метод (dispatch), и как метод в определенном месте программы связывается с местом в байткоде (связывание, binding).
Путаница, короче.
